# Qt with OpenCV - Which one to download

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, open-source, libraries

This must be a very common issue, but I need to download Qt because I am going to learn OpenCV in C++. When I go to Qt-project, there were lot of links, even there are lot of links for the same windows platform! Currently I am coding in C++ with MS Visual Studio Express 2010 (Yes, I am using windows 7 ultimate). I am new to C++ as well.

In order to do OpenCV in Qt, what should I download? My book is using a Qt IDE as well. Can you provide direct links please? Please help!

Comment: "I need to download Qt because I am going to learn OpenCV in C++." You realize that Qt and OpenCV are two completely unrelated libraries, right? You can perfectly use OpenCV without Qt (and vice-versa).

Comment: machan sepalayo uba qt opencv start karanna kalin c++ hodatama karapan. nethnam code gahanna wenna katapadam karala. matath wechcha nisa kiyanne. :)

Comment: @LakshanPerera: Eka awulak wena ekak na machan. C++ ape final year eke subject ekak :). Habai QT, OpenCV nathuwa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using QT there is a IDE named QT Creator. This gives the option of creating various type of projects such as plain C and Plain c++ projects and many more. So you may not need any other c++ IDE as MSVS express. Download the [QT SDK](http://qt-project.org/downloads) to get all the libraries and the IDE together.

For example for windows download the exe in named as "Qt libraries 5.0 Beta 2 for Windows (501MB)"

If you are going to use OpenCV with QT i recommend [OpenCV tutorial 4: OpenCV and Qt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ONxIy8itRA) on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

you can download qt as many ways.

1.as the complete SDK. (you must purchase this)

2.get the qt libraries

3.download the source and build it. (little hard and take a lit of time)

im sure you will go with the 2nd option. so you can download `Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB)` or `Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (VS 2010, 234 MB)`. 1st one is for mingw compiler and the other one is for vc 2010 compiler. you can download this one because already you have vc compiler installed. note that applications build with vc++ are not cross platform. if you need your applications to be cross platform go with mingw compiler. (prebuilt mingw librarys are only compatible with mingw 4.4 version. if you are going to download this first install mingw 4.4 in your computer)

then download and install `Qt Creator 2.6.0 for Windows (51 MB)`. this is a cool IDE for using qt, c++.